# how to have select_tag in form_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

usually in `form_for`

I do `p.text_field :my_colum_name`

but what if I have a select tag?

I tried following but did not work

```
<%=p.select_tag :conditions,options_for_select([ "a", "b", "c" ], "a") %>
```

it says select_tag is an undefined method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
<%= p.select :conditions, [ "a", "b", "c" ] %>
```

Two changes: (1) `select` is the method name when using a FormBuilder, and (2) it takes an array of options, without `options_for_select` (it knows the current value from the object stored in the FormBuilder).

Answer (score 0):

never mind.

```
<%=p.select_tag :conditions,options_for_select([ "a", "b", "c" ], "a") %>
```

works